# Do there exist positive integers $a, b, c$ such that $1/a+1/b+1/c=47/48$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, fractions, integers

So far the only conclusion i have drawn is that $a+b+c$ is greater than 48. However, I cannot make anymore connections that would help me solve the problem. Am I just supposed to "brute force" this by bashing the algebra, or is there some logic I am missing?

Comment: It's not much of an improvement, but you could look at factorisations of $48$ into three positive factors $a, b, c$. Note that none of these factors can be $1$, as this will make the left side too large.

Comment: How did you arrive at your conclusion? Take for example $a=20,b=21,c=22$, then $1/20+1/21+1/22<47/48$. The summation will only get smaller with bigger denominators.

Comment: This is impossible. But we can write this as $\dfrac12+\dfrac13+\dfrac17+\dfrac1{336}.$

Comment: That doesn't fit the requirements of 3 positive integers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The hint.

Let $a\geq b\geq c$.

Hence, $$\frac{47}{48}=\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}\leq\frac{3}{c},$$
which gives $$c\leq\frac{3\cdot48}{47}$$  and from here
$$c\leq3.$$
Also, it's obvious that $c\geq2$.

Now, prove that for $c=2$ and for $c=3$ it's impossible.

For example, let $c=3$.

Hence, $$\frac{31}{48}=\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}\leq\frac{2}{b},$$
which gives $b\leq3$ and since $b\geq c$, we obtain $b=3$, which is impossible.

Comment: Well, if c=2, then I would be left with 23/48. In order for the numerator to b 1, then a and b have to be factors of 48. The only way this would happen is if one of a or b is odd, and the only odd factor is 3, and clearly 20/48 doesn't simplify to a unit fraction.

Comment: @Gerard L. I am ready to write a full proof if you want.

Comment: Well, not yet. Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: Yes, but there is much more easier reasoning.

Comment: I am ready for a full proof.

Comment: I added something. See now.

Answer (score 1):

I will take a different path from Michael. Here we have $\nu_2(48)=4$, hence at least one number among $a,b,c$ has to be a multiple of $16$, and we may assume it is $c$ without loss of generality. We also have $\nu_3(48)=1$. If $c$ is a multiple of both $3$ and $16$ then $\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}$ is between $\frac{46}{48}$ and $\frac{47}{48}$, but $\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}$ is either $\geq 1$ or $\leq\frac{5}{6}$, so, no way. We may assume that $c$ is a multiple of $16$ and $b$ is a multiple of $3$. In such a case $\frac{1}{a}$ has to be between $\frac{28}{48}$ and $\frac{47}{48}$, but sadly there are no unit fractions in such interval.